# Mожно ли выделить сразу весь массив в React?

Tags: reactjs

Есть код: `React.let fixThree = document.querySelectorAll(".underLine")[0];`

Он выделяет один элемент, который в массиве по счёту 0. Mожно ли выделить сразу весь массив?

Comment: пройтись в цикле по всем `document.querySelectorAll(".underLine")`

Comment: убрать [0]? :-)

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин будет ошибка:)

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(".underLine") === ошибка, а document.querySelectorAll(".underLine")[0] === не ошибка?:) Странно:)

Comment: Что за `React.let`?

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll(".underLine") даёт псевдомассив. "Перегнать" его в простой массив можно так:

```
let fixThree = [...document.querySelectorAll(".underLine")]
```

Ну или ещё вариант пользоваться селекторами jQuery, тогда даже циклом не придётся проходится массив, чтобы с ним что-то делать, но это, конечно, не вместе с React